# Google Translate API: How to add newline without changing the phrase meaning

Tags: html, rest, google-translate

I am using google translate rest api to convert string to another language. There are some strings in which I want to insert '\n'. It is changing the meaning of the sentence
e.g.

String:**35 seconds left**

How it's displayed in my App:

35

seconds

left

Translation of the String: **35 ਸਕਿੰਟ ਬਾਕੀ**

Required Output:

35

ਸਕਿੰਟ

ਬਾਕੀ

what I have tried:

q: 35 \n seconds \n left

output: 35 \ n ਸਕਿੰਟ \ n ਖੱਬੇ (here ਖੱਬੇ means left direction not what 
actually required "remaining" i.e. ਬਾਕੀ)

q: `35 <br> seconds <br> left`

output: `35 <br> ਸਕਿੰਟ <br> ਖੱਬੇ`

q: 35 \n seconds \n left

output: `<span class=\"e;notranslate\"e;>35, \\ n</span> ਸਕਿੰਟ <span class=\"e;notranslate\"e;>n</span> ਖੱਬਾ <span class=\"e;notranslate\"e;>\\</span>`

I have also tried adding random number for line break

q: 35 123456 seconds 123456 left

output: 35 123456 ਸਕਿੰਟ 123456 ਬਾਕੀ

this is correct for the above string as I can easily replace 123456 with \n but for some of the other strings it breaks the meaning of the sentence.

However it works correctly on [google](https://translate.google.com/#auto/pa/seconds%20%3Cbr%3E%20left)

I'm using [Rest api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS) and I have tried specifying the format **html**

Answer (score 0):

Translation is a complex task. What you're trying to do is enforce a specific syntax into a sentence, then translate it, and hope that the same syntax is applicable in the new language. This is not always the case, and would require the application to know the semantics of the inserted syntax (in your case linebreaks and numbers). You might want to read [this article](https://www.ulatus.com/translation-blog/translation-space-issues-and-line-breaks-alignment/) describing the issue in more detail.

Instead of trying to guess what you mean when you insert linebreaks into a sentence, it just assumes that you are starting a new one. This will cause each line to be translated individually, resulting in a non-optimal translation.

How I would approach this problem, would be to translate the string, e.g.

`35 seconds left` ➡️ `35 ਸਕਿੰਟ ਬਾਕੀ`.

Then I would replace the spaces in output with linebreaks, resulting in the following:

`35 ਸਕਿੰਟ ਬਾਕੀ` ➡️ `35\nਸਕਿੰਟ\nਬਾਕੀ`

***Let me stretch that this is not general solution, but it probably work in many languages, since your use-case is rather simple, i.e. short sentences.***

Comment: thanks for the answer but space is not an option for me bro. That was just an example I do have longer sentences which needed to be converted. I tried alternatives to make it work but it just break the meaning.